# af:selectOneChoice constantly re-fetches data

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have .jspx page, that includes .jsff. In .jsff I have:

```
<af:selectOneChoice id="soc" autoSubmit="true" required="false"
                                               label="Select" contentStyle="width:200px"
                                               binding="#{SOME_BEAN.soc}"
                                               labelStyle="width:6em;"
                                               unselectedLabel=""
                                               valueChangeListener="#{SOME_BEAN.handleSocChanged}"
                                               inlineStyle="margin-left:100px;">
        <af:forEach var="var" items="#{SOME_BEAN.someListOfDTO}">
                <af:selectItem id="si" value="#{var.field1}" label="#{var.field1}-#{var.field2}"/>
        </af:forEach>                          

</af:selectOneChoice>
```

But **items** in foreach is actualy expression to the method **getSomeListOfDTO** which returns list of DTO objects. So there is no such field **someListOfDTO** in SOME_BEAN.

Is that ok?

Because I'm facing such trouble, that my program constantly calls  **getSomeListOfDTO**.

Answer (score 1):

I checked ADF demo page and I found that you could use the `<f:selectItems>` tag instead of looping selectItem one by one via `<af:foreach>`

following is the reference link for you:
Select One Choice Demo page:
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/components/selectOneChoice.jspx;jsessionid=n1LyHWuGDnmH8mVGt0H641vsttd0GfYviCSYIavT9l-g9gXaiHBm!198932670

and the source page 
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/components/selectOneChoice.jspx.source